# I am facing an issue while running batch command to push the code from local server to repository (Gitlab)

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci

Here is the attached YML file and error description for more information.

[image: Error]

**Below is the yml code to execute bat file in GitLab:**

```
job_1:
   tags :
     -ci
  before_script:
  - echo "This is the before_script."
  - echo "Attempting to run the WindowsCommand 35 version-application.bat file..."
  - call C:\ADM\appian-adm-versioning-client-2.5.9\version-application.bat
  script:
    - version-application.bat -action "addContents" -application_path "C:\Demo\Application Exports\ASD_App_12172019.zip" -commit_message "Sdlc application 12242019"
```

How can I make this job work?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant error seems to be:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: version-manager.properties  
  (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Check in the [Appian documentation](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/19.4/Application_Deployment_Guidelines.html)  if/how that file should be present.
But you should at least version it and push it, in order for the gitlab-ci job to use it.

Comment: We have checked Appian document but no pointers regarding this error. I am not clear with your statement "But you should at least version it and push it".. I am trying to push it to repository where it is failing in version-application.bat

Comment: I meant `git add version-manager.properties`, then commit and push

Comment: Agree with you this solution work for me , but my question is i use the below following script in Command line as well as in jenkins:                                             [ C:\ADM\appian-adm-versioning-client-2.5.9\version-application.bat -action "addContents" -application_path "C:\Demo\Application Exports\ASD_App_12172019.zip" -commit_message "Sdlc application 12242019" ] it runs and executed as execpted but in gitlab i am not getting the pointer to execute this script

Comment: if you can help me then i will be very thankful to you .@https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc

Comment: Thanks @VonC now i can execute my files thanks for the suggestion, it help me a lot .

Comment: Well done! Sorry for the delay: I am with the family.